# best database for a real estate system

Tags: security, rdbms, storage, crash

Which is the best database suits for a real estate system.
Considering the storage space, security, crash recoveries, speed etc.
There will be around 1000 fields and trillions of rows!!!

Comment: Trillions of rows? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

The best database will be the one you (or the person in charge) know how to administer and handle. Besides software resources, one important question is the human resources you have available for your project. Oracle, Sql Server... will all be useless if no one in your company knows how to use those DBMS.